# glass fish 3.1.2 start failed in netbeans 7.2

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I've installed Netbeans 7.2. with GlassFish Server 3.1.2  but when I run web application the default jsp page or any other jsp pages I got the error:

> GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Start Failed
>
> C:\Users****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1022:
>   Deployment error: GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Start Failed See the server
>   log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 47 seconds)

**build-impl.xml**

> < target depends="init,-init-cos,compile,
>   compile-jsps,-do-compile-single-jsp,-pre-dist,-do-tmp-dist-with-manifest,-do-tmp-dist-without-manifest,-pre-run-deploy,
>   -pre-nbmodule-run-deploy,-run-deploy-nb,-init-deploy-ant,-deploy-ant,-run-deploy-am,-post-nbmodule-run-deploy,-post-run-deploy,
>   -do-update-breakpoints" name="run-deploy"/>
>
> < target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
>
> < nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false"
>   forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

////////////////////////

> glassFish Server 3.1.2
>
> SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port
>   within range:
>   8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@788a7b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution. My 8080 port was reserved by Oracle. So I edited the domain.xml file inside glassfish\domains\domain1\ config\domain.xml file.

I replaced the port 8080 with 9999 and replaced the file. After that I added the glassfish server to netbeans, and now it is working.

Thank You everyone.

Comment: FYI: you should not have 8080 reserved by a user program service ,good practice

Answer (score 1):

The error message states it clearly:

> No free port within range: 8080

Probably there is another instance of Glassfish (or any other server) running on your system. Try to find it out by calling `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

### **Another option to solve this probs

**Enter the following on the command line:

netstat -ao

The active TCP addresses and ports will be listed — locate the line with local address “0.0.0.0:80″ and note the PID value.

Now right-click the task bar and select Start Task Manager. Navigate to the Processes tab and, if necessary, click View > Select Columns… to ensure “PID (Process Identifier)” is checked. You can now locate the PID you noted above. The description and properties should help you determine which application is using the port.

The Task Manager allows you to kill the process, but be a little wary about doing that — especially if it’s “NT Kernel & System”.****

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
i solved it by configuring the glassfish with jdk7 instead of jdk8.
i dont know why it wasnt working with jdk8 but now the glassfish is running.